# Java Counter Program

Tags: java, counter, increment

I am working on a program where a user gives two numbers. The first is the number that the counter will count up to. The second is the increment it will do so. The program has a starting number of one and should add all the numbers together that add up the first given number. For example, The user inputs numbers 7 and 2. So the program should do the following: 1+3+5+7 and would equal 16. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong with my program.

```
System.out.print("Please enter your first positive number: ");
int n1 = user.nextInt();
System.out.print("Please enter your second positive number: ");
int n2 = user.nextInt();

int sum = 1;

while(sum <= n1)
{
    sum += n2;
}
System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, you are stopping when your sum exceeds `n1`. And for each loop, you are adding `n2`, not the last value incremented by `n2`.

Try this which uses a for loop to loop through the real increment values (which increase each iteration):

```
System.out.print("Please enter your first positive number: ");
int n1 = user.nextInt();
System.out.print("Please enter your second positive number: ");
int n2 = user.nextInt();

// start your sum at zero
int sum = 0;

// loop increasing the increment value until it exceeds the users input
for(int increment = 1; increment <= n1; increment += n2) {
    sum += increment;
}
System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

Comment: This is a lot nicer than my half-assed attempt.

Comment: Actually, this isn't that much different from your original answer.

Comment: Thank You! Looking at this now, it makes total sense.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it.